# Django - Display value of CommaSeparatedIntegerField

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I display in HTML value of CommaSeparatedIntegerField ?

Here is some code:

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    vals = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Test"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import Test


def test(request):
    mymodel = Test
    return render(request, 'main.html')
```

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: I want to display value of `oceny = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=150)` in my HTML.

Comment: what have you tried and what's your problem? if you have time please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for bad asked question. I want to display value of field `oceny` on my page, put it into variable, `{{ oceny }}`

Comment: and you have empty data? or wrong data? show your view code please, add your code to the question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a [child of `CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#CommaSeparatedIntegerField). So, you can display it simply like this:

```
{{ oceny }}
```

But first, make sure that you send it in your view:

```
def test(request):
    my_object = Test.objects.get(pk=1)
    return render(request, 'oceny/main.html', {'oceny': my_object.oceny})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what should I add into my views.py ?